# Proving convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left({n \over n+1}\right)^{n^2} $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left({n \over n+1}\right)^{n^2} $$

We have :
$$ \left({n \over n+1}\right)^n = \left({1 \over 1+{1\over n}}\right)^n = 
{1 \over  \left( 1+ {1 \over n}\right)^n}$$ 
So,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left({n \over n+1}\right)^n = {1 \over e} \lt 1 $$

And the series converges by Cauchy criterion.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: yes u r correct ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By comparing this series with respect to this geometric series we found that, your series converge to the a number less than $1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{2}{3})^4+(\frac{3}{4})^9+(\frac{4}{5})^{16}...< \frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{1}{2})^3+(\frac{1}{2})^4+...=1$$

If we could a more restricted upper bound to series, we reach to more accurate number. 
To reach a lower bound I use similar way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{2}{3})^4+(\frac{3}{4})^9+(\frac{4}{5})^{16}+...> \frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2})^3+(\frac{1}{2})^5++(\frac{1}{2})^7...=\frac{2}{3}$$

So:
$$\frac{2}{3}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}<1$$

Comment: Thank you. 
However, is writing the inequalities as you did sufficient or do we have to develop more to make the inequalities more obvious?

Comment: We could reach to a upper and lower bound for this series. So it absolutely converge to a limited value. But finding accurate value of convergence take more time or maybe difficult for some series.